# Android+Eclipse+Flixel - Can't Find Superclass

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working through this tutorial:

http://www.bukisa.com/articles/223910_creating-a-game-on-google-android-game-with-flixel-getting-started

But I seem to be having a breakdown between steps 4 and 5. I dl/unzip the Flixel source files into the "Flixel Demo" folder, but they're not being recognized/imported into Eclipse? So when I go to select the org.flixel.FlxState superclass for the MenuState class, the only superclass available is java.lang.Object.

As a note, I've also had trouble with Flex being able to find files that I dl/unzip. It returns an error saying it can't find my lib files.

Any ideas? I'm sure this is just super noobness.

Comment: +1 for the interesting link :)

Comment: Why did you tag this w/ Adobe Flex?

Comment: Sorry but did you perform a refresh on your project in eclipse ?

Comment: I think one of the problems is that you're trying to use Flex.  Flixel is a Flash gaming engine and this article seems to have ported it to Java.  You only need to import a Java project, not a Flex/Flash project.

Comment: Flex and Flixel/Eclipse are different issues. I was just noting that I'd had similar problems with FLex, in a separate project. I'm mainly asking about that tutorial I linked to, which uses Eclipse and Flixel, and a Java project (not Flex).

Comment: [+1 for the interesting link :)]²

Comment: @NemoStein and @thbruyelle will you post here where you downloaded and unzipped the FLixel source to? Was it just the "Flixel Demo" folder?

Comment: @Meredith I've completed the tutorial without issue. After unzipping the Flixel SDK in the project, you have to refresh the project in Eclipse and then you can keep going

Answer (score 0):

After you extracted the zip file into your project folder go to the Package Explorer in Eclipse and click on the project and select File > Refresh (or F5). Then do a Project > Clean.

In the Package Explorer underneath your project name you should see the "src" directory, and under that you should see a package name like "org.flixel". If it's working right you should be able to open up that package and see all the Flixel classes like FlxBlock.java and they should all have a "J" icon where the "J" is filled in with color. If you don't see that then either you extracted it in the wrong place or the project was not created right.